# Toastr - Target specific popup

Tags: jquery, toastr

I am just starting out with `Toastr`, although I have used `jGrowl` before.

My question is as follows, if I have multiple `Toastr` popups visible, is there anyway that I can target a specific one in order to remove it?

I cannot seem to find any documentation around setting and targeting using ID's...

Answer (score 0):

The toastr() function returns the div of the toast, with which you can do what you like.

You can try this out in your browser's js console (this is chrome):
[image: chrome inspector screenshot]

Comment: perhaps i did not explain myself well enough. I have a loop, whereby I open a single (or multiple) toastr popups. Each popup has an input box with a button. Once the user fills in the input box and clicks the button, I then need to close that specific popup.

Comment: Ah, you could add a click handler to the button that gets the parent toast div via the jquery [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) selector.

Comment: I finally managed to do this using your suggestion. I am using the onlick event to find the input box contained within the DIV element. Using that, I then use $("#inputboxname" + id).parent().parent().hide(); - this seems to work... Thanks so much for putting me on the right track.

Comment: @SQLGuru Can you explain more about how you solved this?